# Combine filtering posts and loading more posts

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

**In Angular and Firestore, how do I best combine *filter* functionality with *load-more* functionality?**

*Use-case: I initially want to load only the latest 10 posts. But I want to allow the user to filter by post-title using an input-field. This filter should search through **all** posts, not just the latest 10.*

How do I achieve this conceptually?

- If I loaded **all** the posts from Firestore in one go, I could easily filter by post-title in my component (or using a pipe with *ngFor).
- However, if I only loaded **some** of the posts from Firestore, then filtering this way obviously would only apply to those posts that have been loaded. Hence if I searched for the post-title of a post that has not yet been loaded, it obviously would not work.

So I assume I have to move my filtering logic from the frontend to the backend *somehow*.

How do I do this? Do I have to have my title-filter query Firestore on every single keystroke?

Doesn't this mean I loose any potential savings I received from loading only some data to now making dozens of search queries to the backend? And hence might it not be better to just load all the posts in one go initially, and then perform the filtering in the frontend?

**How do people do this?**

Comment: Instead of sending the request on every keystroke, typically you'd introduce a debounce time, to limit to number of requests

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have a UI like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Search: ______________________         |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
...
```

I then use the logic that:

- If the search is empty, I show the top 10 items from the collection.
- If the search has a value, I show the top 10 items from the collection that match the search term.

The second step does require that the search options of the app fit within Firestore's query model, which I ensure.

With this approach I always get at most 10 items, (or whatever number of items reasonably constitutes a screen full of content).